# Best framework for Android and iOS game?

Tags: android, google-play-services, game-engine

I want to build an arithmetic game for Android and iOS. It wouldn't need to much performance, a simple 2D game framework should be enough.

I was thinking about whether using LibGDX or HTML5 framework.

If it affects the choice, it's likely that the game will incorporate Play Services

What do you suggest?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I doubt HTML5 is good enough in terms of performance. libgdx may not be as good as [Corona SDK](https://coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/). Corona supports many platforms (Android, iOS, Windows Phone, ...).

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try it out